# Perl Facebook::Graph API v2.x

Tags: perl, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook::Graph Perl module for long time to authorize users on a website, recently I am getting message on facebook site saying:

```
You must upgrade this app to Graph API v2.x
v1.0 will be deprecated on April 30, 2015
Learn how to upgrade
```

Where to specify the version number in the module to use the Graph API v2.x.

Comment: https://github.com/rizen/Facebook-Graph/issues/53

Comment: The author said `I'm thinking it's time to depreciate this module in favor of https://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook::OpenGraph`

Answer (score 2):

Migrate your code to [Facebook::OpenGraph](https://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook::OpenGraph) as [suggested](https://github.com/rizen/Facebook-Graph/issues/53) by the [author](https://github.com/rizen) itself. On issue 53 you'll find a [patch](https://github.com/rizen/Facebook-Graph/commit/e76bad479b76730fdf668a343cee661cbfe11afd) to  lib/Facebook/Graph/Role/Uri.pm to do just what you asked for, which clearly does not deal with any API change:

```
 -4,7 +4,7 @@ use Any::Moose 'Role';
use URI;
sub uri {
- return URI->new('https://graph.facebook.com')
+ return URI->new('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1')
}
```